Kivy - RecycleView not reflecting changes in it's data
I am trying to build a following kivy app:

Select a folder on screen one
Popup window comes up showing progress of populating a list of dictionaries with files info from selected folder
Once this is done, pop up closes, app switches automatically to screen 2
screen 2 will display files of the directory (using RecycleView)

this is where I am:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle, RoundedRectangle
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior


# from logic import analyze_directory

import os
from threading import Thread
import time
import sys


file_list = [{'file': 'a', 'path': 'c/ddd'},
             {'file': 'b', 'path': 'c..d'}]
class RoundedButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RoundedButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background_normal = ''  # Disable the default background
        self.background_color = (0, 0, 0, 0)  # Make the background transparent
        self.color_normal = (0.2, 0.6, 1, .8)  # Normal color
        self.color_down = (0.1, 0.3, 0.43, 1)  # Color when pressed
        with self.canvas.before:
            self.color_instruction = Color(*self.color_normal)
            self.rect = RoundedRectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos, radius=[20])
            self.bind(pos=self.update_rect, size=self.update_rect)

        self.bind(on_press=self.on_button_press, on_release=self.on_button_release)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size

    def on_button_press(self, *args):
        self.color_instruction.rgba = self.color_down

    def on_button_release(self, *args):
        self.color_instruction.rgba = self.color_normal


class FileChooser(FileChooserListView):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)


class IntroScreen(Screen):
   pass


class DrivesLayout(BoxLayout):

    drive_buttons = []
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.spacing = "3dp"
        self.size_hint_y = 0.17

        drives = self.get_available_drives()

        for index, drive in enumerate(drives):
            drive_button = Button(text=drive, size_hint=(None, None), size=(30, 30), background_normal="",background_color=(0.1,0.1,0.1,1))
            drive_button.bind(on_press=lambda instance, drive=drive: self.select_drive(drive))
            self.add_widget(drive_button)
            self.drive_buttons.append(drive_button)
            if index == 0:  # Highlight the first drive button
                drive_button.background_normal = ""
                drive_button.background_color = (0, 0.5, 0,1)


    def get_available_drives(self):
        drives = []
        drive_buttons = []
        if os.name == 'nt':  # Windows
            import win32api
            bitmask = win32api.GetLogicalDrives()
            for letter in range(65, 91):
                if bitmask & 1:
                    drives.append(chr(letter) + ":/")
                bitmask >>= 1
        else:  # Unix/Linux/MacOS
            drives = [os.path.join('/', d) for d in os.listdir('/') if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('/', d))]
        return drives

    def select_drive(self, drive):

        for button in self.drive_buttons:
            button.background_color = (0.1,0.1,0.1,1)  # Reset background color of all buttons
            button.spacing ="30dp"
            # print(DirectorySelectorScreen.ids.file_chooser)
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.get_screen("dirsel").ids.file_chooser.path = drive

        self.drive_buttons[self.get_available_drives().index(drive)].background_normal = ""  # removes grey background (otherwise artifact white dots)
        self.drive_buttons[self.get_available_drives().index(drive)].background_color = (0, 0.5, 0,1 )  # Highlight selected button


class DirectorySelectorScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)


    label_text = StringProperty('Select a Directory to be checked for duplicate files:')

    # def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
    #     # This method is called after the widget is fully initialized
    #     self.label_text = self.ids.file_chooser.path
    def get_current_path(self):
        return self.ids.file_chooser.path
    def selection_to_label(self):

        if self.ids.file_chooser.selection[0]:
            self.label_text = self.ids.file_chooser.selection[0]

        else:
           self.label_text = self.ids.file_chooser.path

    def submit_path(self):

        dir_path = ''
        if self.ids.file_chooser.selection:
            self.label_text = self.ids.file_chooser.selection[0]
            self.ids.file_chooser.selection = []
            dir_path = self.label_text
        else:
            self.label_text = self.ids.file_chooser.path

        dir_path = self.label_text # path for the logic
        # print(dir_path)
        self.manager.current = 'results'

        self.show_popup(dir_path)

    def show_popup(self, dir_path):

        # Create the popup layout
        popup_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=10, spacing=10)
        self.progress_bar = ProgressBar(max=100)
        self.progress_label = Label(text='Progress: 0%')

        popup_layout.add_widget(self.progress_label)
        popup_layout.add_widget(self.progress_bar)

        # Create the popup window
        self.popup = Popup(title='Analyzing Directory '+ dir_path,
                           content=popup_layout,
                           size_hint=(0.8, 0.4))

        self.popup.open()

        # Start the directory analysis in a separate thread
        Thread(target=self.analyze_directory, args=(dir_path,)).start()

    def update_progress(self, progress):
        self.progress_bar.value = progress
        self.progress_label.text = f'Progress: {int(progress)}%'

        # Ensure UI updates are handled in the main thread
        App.get_running_app().root.do_layout()


    def analyze_directory(self, path):
        global file_list

        try:
            # faster way to count files for progress bar but problem with permissions
            total_files = count_files_in_directory(path)
        except:
        # backup way of counting the files for the progress bar
            total_files = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(path)])
        files_processed = 0

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                file_info = {}
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
                file_creation_date = os.path.getctime(file_path)
                file_info = {
                    'file': file,
                    'size': file_size,
                    'created': file_creation_date,
                    'path': file_path
                }
                file_list.append(file_info)

                # Update progress
                files_processed += 1
                progress = (files_processed / total_files) * 100
                self.update_progress(progress)
        print(total_files)
        print(f'print from end of analyze_dir: {file_list}')

        self.update_progress(100)  # Ensure the progress bar reaches 100%
        time.sleep(1)
        self.popup.dismiss()  # Close the popup after completion
        ResultsScreen.data = file_list
        # You can further process `file_list` as needed

    def count_files_in_directory(self, path):
        pass
def count_files_in_directory(path):
        file_count = 0
        with os.scandir(path) as entries:
            for entry in entries:
                if entry.is_file():
                    file_count += 1
                elif entry.is_dir():
                    file_count += count_files_in_directory(entry.path)
        return file_count

class recycleView(RecycleView):
    pass
class ResultsScreen(RecycleDataViewBehavior,Screen):

    global file_list
    data = ListProperty()
    recycleView = ObjectProperty(None)
    data = file_list
    # print(data)

    def refresh_view(self):
        global file_list
        print(f'printing from refresh_view before refresh: {self.recycleView.data}')
        self.ids.recycleView.data = []
        self.ids.recycleView.data = file_list
        print(f'this should be updated filelist from refresh_view: {file_list}')
        self.ids.recycleView.refresh_from_data()

class ItemWidget(BoxLayout):
    file = StringProperty()
    path = StringProperty()


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
   pass


class GruntleDuplicateFileRemoverApp(App):
   pass


GruntleDuplicateFileRemoverApp().run()

and the .kv.file:


MyScreenManager:
    DirectorySelectorScreen:
    ResultsScreen:
    IntroScreen:


<IntroScreen>:
    name: "intro"
    Button:
        text: 'intro screen'

<ResultsScreen>:
    on_pre_enter: root.refresh_view()
    recycleView: recycleView
    name: "results"
    RecycleView:
        id: recycleView
        data: root.data
        viewclass: 'ItemWidget'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(80)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
            # spacing: dp(5)

<ItemWidget>:
    Label:
        text: root.file
<Drives>:
    size_hint_y: 0.2


<DirectorySelectorScreen>:
    name: "dirsel"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: path_label
            text: root.label_text
            font_size: "25dp"
            size_hint_y: None
            padding: dp(10), dp(30), dp(10), dp(20)
            text_size: self.width, None
            halign: 'center'
            height: self.texture_size[1]
        DrivesLayout:
        # Button:
        #     on_press: root.do_something()
        BoxLayout:
            FileChooserListView:
                id: file_chooser
                dirselect: True
                show_hidden: False
        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0.2
            RoundedButton:
                text: 'select'
                size_hint: None, None
                size:(dp(100), dp(40))
                on_release: root.submit_path()


The Problem I have is that the screen 2 is not showing the populated files, but only default dummy data (which i hardcoded in order to see that RecycleView is loading data from designated global variable). With the help of print statements in various places I can see that the global variable file_list is updated with the files-info, but I don't know how to make the RecycleView update to reflect new data.
Please help!
I have tried to Implement refresh_view function, that has got refresh_from_data() in it, but it doesn't work.
I suspect the refresh_view() is called before the list is populated, perhaps because the data is collected in analyze_dir() function that is run in new thread due to need of not blocking the main thread so that the progress bar is showing correctly...?
Thanks for any help!

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

I think you need to change the line:
ResultsScreen.data = file_list

to:
self.manager.get_screen('results').data = file_list

The first code changes the ListProperty to a simple list in the ResultsScreen class. The second changes the value of the ListProperty in the ResultsScreen instance to the file_list.
And you should also remove the line in the ResultsScreen:
data = file_list

which is also replacing the ListProperty. If you want the default value of data to be the file_list, you can define the ListProperty as:
data = ListProperty(file_list)

Note that this uses a shallow copy of file_list, so later changes to file_list are not automatically reflected in the data ListProperty.

Hi John, Thank you for your input. When I change the first line you suggested, there is no change in my code, still displays only the hardcoded dict. When I remove data = file_list and replace with data=ListProperty(file_list), the app crashes... I think the data should be just an ordinary python list of dictionaries. The problem is that the file_list inside the refresh method is not being updated with an updated data. When I print out the content of file_list from outside the refresh_view method, the list is updated, but from inside of the method it is not...

Your refresh_view() method is being called before the file_list is updated because of the on_pre_enter: root.refresh_view() in your kv. I don't think that is even needed, try commenting out that line. I expect you will then get an error message from the RecycleVew.

Commenting out on_pre_enter:  root.refresh_view()  in .kv did not change anything.

Are you getting any error messages?

No error messages, as long as I don't use ListProperty().

You need the data to be a ListProperty, in order for the kv line data: root.data to work. Otherwise you can assign the data in the analyze_directory() method as self.manager.get_screen('results').ids.recycleView.data = file_list.

File "C:\Users\StudioGoat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\recyclelayout.py", line 310, in compute_sizes_from_data            w, h = s = item.get('width', s[0]), item.get('height', s[1])                                   ~^^^  TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

above is the error I got when I tried to assign the data in the analyze_directory() method as self.manager.get_screen('results').ids.recycleView.data = file_list

and below is the error I get when in refresh_view(self) assign data = ListProperty().    File "C:\Users\StudioGoat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\recycleview\__init__.py", line 320, in refresh_views      lm.compute_sizes_from_data(data, f)    File "C:\Users\StudioGoat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\recyclelayout.py", line 310, in compute_sizes_from_data            w, h = s = item.get('width', s[0]), item.get('height', s[1])                                   ~^^^  TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Both of those errors indicate that the data is getting updated, but that the data includes incorrect information. The dictionaries in the data list includes keys for properties of the viewclass and the corresponding value to be assigned. It appears that your data includes a size key, but the value is not a tuple (size is expected to be of the form (width, height). The value for size in your data appears to be a single integer.

OMG, thanks John! After changing the size keyword to file_size, it finally works! So in essence, size is something like a  reserved keyword in data of recycleview, requiring a tuple with (width, height), is that correct?

p.s. John, could you update your answer so that in addition it also contains your latest comment? Or should I just accept it as it is? Sorry, this is my first ever post here and not sure what's the best way to make it most helpful for others and credit/reward you for resolving this problem.

The size is not a reserved word, but it is a property of every Widget. So if you include size in your data, the RecycleView will try to assign the provided value to the size of the Widget (viewclass). That is true for any property of the viewclass.

Got you. Interesting. Lots to learn!
